# Проблем с платежными системами битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

1. Создал свою доставку в службах доставки (в настройках сразу же
   выставил ограничения по платежным системам, например оплата онлайн,
   оплата картой в офисе)
2. В init.php написал обработчик для события
   OnSaleComponentOrderOneStepDelivery чтобы удалить все доставки и
   оставить только свою если у товара есть определенный флаг.

Открываю форму заказа, вижу свою доставку, вижу все формы оплаты построились так как нужно, исходя из настроек ограничений службы.

Переключаю тип плательщика на юр.лиц а потом снова на физ.лицо и вижу что доставка моя, а вот платежки вылезли левые, не те что использовались при ограничении для созданной доставки.

В чем может быть проблема? (левых событий в коде не нашел для платежных систем, компонент тоже не кастомный)

UPD: из того что заметил: если не помечать доставку выбранной а потом выбрать, то произойдет refresh на AJAX запросе и тогда службы строятся верно. Но как на back-end сделать чтобы доставка была уже выбрана та, которая нужна? Я просто ставит Checked = 'Y' в массиве доставок.

Comment: Может у тебя просто не выбрана эта служба доставки после переключения?

Comment: а там больше не из чего выбирать, т.к она остается одна и автоматом стоит как выбранная

Comment: Вы ограничения выставили и для физ и для юр-типов?

Comment: ограничения только по платежным система в службе. Проблема не в настройках.
Проблема в том что я битриксу говорю что галочка моей службы checked. Но платежные системы грузит от другой службы доставки. Смог это решить убрав checked, только тогда приходится из одной службы (в списке) жать на нее чтобы выбрать, тогда происходит ajax запрос который перезагружает компонент и появляются мои платежные системы.

Но у этого решения есть минусы. 1) нужно выбирать каждый раз службу (хотя она и так одна в списке)
2) оформить заказ могут без доставки вообще если не выберут службу